# When to use the demonstrative adjective "este" before "es (noun)" rather than "esto"

Tags: gramática, pronombres-demostrativos

My understanding of esto vs. este/esta is that **esto** substitutes the noun/pronoun whereas **este/esta** helps identify another noun/pronoun.

However, my intuition broke down in the following examples found on FluentU:

> Este es mi perro.
> Esta es mi casa.
> Esto es un carro.

Does it have something to do with the possesive adjective **mi**?

If you could help me to build some intuition as to how I know which one to use, I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is correct and here's the tricky bit:

Este es mi perro. = can be said = Este perro es mio.
Esta es mi casa. = Esta casa es mia.

So, there you can clearly see the adjectival use of este and esta.

Whereas:
Esto es un carro. ≠ Esto carro does not work.

The pronouns can function as nouns. **Whereas *esto*, a noun cannot be an adjective**.

Answer (score 5):

The neuter demonstrative "esto" (as well as "eso" and "aquello") is used to refer to something that is not defined (this thing, that thing) or to a situation:

- Esto (que tiene un chasis y cuatro ruedas) es un carro. (This object, with a body and four wheels, is a car.)
- Esto es un desastre. (This is a disaster.)

The neuter form can also be used pejoratively even for people, for example:

- ¿Eso es un amigo? (Is that what you call a friend?)

as opposed to:

- ¿Ese es tu amigo? (Is that (guy) your friend?)